# Occupation numbers under the independent electron assumption

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, density-functional-theory

I am working with DFT, so the assumption is that the many-body Hamiltonian describes many independent electrons. I have solved the eigen-system and received the energy levels of the electrons and the eigenvectors. Now I want to get the density matrix. However, the density matrix, as you know, depends on the occupation numbers.

I assume that the occupation numbers themselves, $n_i$, are given by the Fermi-Dirac distribution. Assuming that is true, I need to calculate
$$
 \exp\Big([e_i - \mu]/[k_BT] \Big) = {n_i}^{-1} - 1
$$
Question 1: Is this valid reasoning for the independent electron model?

Question 2: How will I get $\mu$? It would seem reasonable to choose $\mu$ equal to the Fermi energy.

Comment: Why are you needing the density matrix? To what level of approximation are you intending to be satisfied with?